# Swipe to delete swift custom UItable

Tags: uitableview, custom-controls, swipe, swift3

I can create swipe to delete which works wonderfully on my standard UItable view but the same code does not allow editable on my UItable view that has a number of extra things in each row ? Any ideas as to why this might be the case and whether I can add this option

[image: works fine - simple UItable view]

[image: cant swipe at all on this one]

I am using swift only

Comment: Still looking for answer?